# Configure keyboard combination to switch apps

Tags: macos, mac

<kbd>Command-Tab</kbd> displays app list to switch between them, well nice feature. But can I customise this keyboard combination to use a single key to accomplish application switching?

Comment: Customize to do what?

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you want to change the shortcut to something else, change the way Cmd-Tab/app switching works or even something else?

Comment: What u mean by Cmd?

Comment: The Command key

Comment: I want to assign some other key (preferably a single key) to do the same job instead of cmd+tab.

Comment: I'd like to do the same thing, but do not know how to do it. I have two applications, between which I want to switch often.

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of a way to do it with a single key if you enable the function keys to work without holding down fn.

Then you can assign one of the function keys (F1, F2 etc.) to "Move focus to next window".

First enable "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys like this:
[image: Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys]

Then assign the "Move focus to next window" to one of the function keys like this:
[image: Move focus to next window]

Comment: "Move focus to next window" isn't the same as ⌘⇥ which switches between apps?

Answer (score -2):

You may or may not like Witch: http://manytricks.com/witch/

Comment: Could you expand on how this answers the question?